# Is there anyway in SQL Server to know when a column is added to the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is any way in SQL Server to know when a specific column is added/modified in a table.

When I try the following code, I can not see any track of columns, it includes only tables and foreign keys.

```
select * from sys.objects
order by modify_date desc
```

any idea?

Comment: Two word answer: [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx).

Comment: As far as I understood DDLTrigger is something I need to setup on my database in order to be able to track changes. I wish I could find out the last_modified date of column on ANY database without pre-configurations. is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd take a look at [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182602.aspx) and see if you can create a solution from the info there.

I'll admit to never using them for this purpose, and it may be overkill for your needs but it should do the trick.

**EDIT :** Oh, and [DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989.aspx) may be less involved and still give you what you need.

Comment: As far as I understood DDLTrigger is something I need to setup on my database in order to be able to track changes. I wish I could find out the last_modified date of column on ANY database without pre-configurations. is it possible?

Comment: Then Event Notifications may be your only option. From MSDN: *You can specify an event notification to occur in response to a statement made on all objects in the current database or all objects on an instance of SQL Server*