# find out who added new column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very critical database with live customer data, we actually maintain this database. Someone have created in a critical table, a new column. I need to find out who created this column.

I am using SQL Server2005

This is a very critical issue. I have to answer to administration so quickly so any answer in this regard is very helpful.

Very very thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have transaction log backups for the time of the change? And do you have login auditing enabled?

Comment: Yes we have transaction log as well as auditing is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the EventData() Function with DDL triggers
Create the event log table

```
--CREATE TABLE EvtLog  
(
PostTime DATETIME,
LoginName NVARCHAR(100),
EventType NVARCHAR(100), 
TSQLCommand NVARCHAR(2000)  
)
GO
--Create the DDL trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trPreventTblChange 
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
DECLARE @Data XML
SET @Data = EventData()
INSERT EvtLog (PostTime, LoginName, EventType, TSQLCommand) 
VALUES
(GETDATE(),
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), CURRENT_USER),   
@Data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),  
@Data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)') ) ;
GO
```

More info about [DDL_TABLE_EVENTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180713%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi And what now to do

Answer (score 4):

Depending on when the change occurred you may be able to determine this from the default trace (requires you to have not disabled it and for it to not have rolled over 5 times and deleted the trace file in the meantime).

See my answer to [Determining how a schema change occurred?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10718/3690) on the DBA site for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that after the fact, unless you've pre-configured the DB to do so.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498459/62576) can provide more information. There's also a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12283370/62576) that provides some more details.